# Function with extrema 1, 1/4, 1/9, ...

Tags: functions, special-functions

I am looking for a function $F(x)$ which has an infinite number of extrema, and whose values at those extrema are of the form $1/n^2$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

To clarify, I don't want a function whose extrema are *at* $x=1,1/4,1/9,\ldots$. Instead, I want the function itself to take these values at the extrema.

Edit: To clarify, there shouldn't be multiple extrema with value F(x)=0!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: For integer $n$, let $f(x) = n^{-2}$ whenever $x \in [n - 0.1, n+0.1]$ and interpolate linearly to get values elsewhere.

Comment: What do you want to do at $x=0?$  The two examples in answers have maxima like you asked for but also minima at $F(x)=0$ in between.

Comment: Hi Ross, thanks for your help! I do not want there to be minima at F(x)=0 in between! Instead, the function would ideally have the following extrema, in order of increasing x: 1, 1/9, 1/4, 1/16, etc. The reason for this ordering being that we need minima between each maxima, as you said

Comment: @B.Eneru: $ 1, 1/9, 1/4, 1/16$ is not the sequence that you used in your question.

Comment: If the function is continuous, you can't have those be successive extrema.  $1$ would be a maximum, but then $1/4$ would be a minimum, then you can't have $1/9$ be a maximum without some more extrema in between.

Comment: If you want to swap $1/9$ and $1/4$ you should edit the question.  You should also indicate how the series continues.  I don't understand what is in the $\ldots$ after $1/16$ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A simple one, aside from the problem near $x=0,$ is $F(x)=(\frac 1n \cos x\pi)^2$ where $n$ is the closest integer to $x$.  The cosine term takes values $\pm 1$ at all the integers.

Comment: For $n \in \Bbb N$ you have $F(n) = 1/n^2$, but $F'(n) = -2/n^3$, so those points are not extrema.

Comment: @MartinR:  you are correct.  I have patched it up.

Comment: Interestingly, your new function is even continuous ($\sin(\pi x) = 0$ where $n$ "jumps")

Answer (score 1):

Does this fit the bill?

$f(x) = \frac 1{x^2}|\cos \pi x|$

It will also have extrema equal to $0$ in between.  But you can't have a chain of extrema that is monotonically decreasing.  Each minimum must be less than the maxima on either side.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for your help! This is great, but actually I do not want there to be minima at F(x)=0 in between! Instead, the function would ideally have the following extrema, in order of increasing x: 1, 1/9, 1/4, 1/16, etc. The reason for this ordering being that we need minima between each maxima, as you said (I repeat this in the comments above)